# How to convert xml variable to xml file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, dictionary

I convert my dictionary to xml but I cant save that in xml file

```
from dict2xml import dict2xml

xml = dict2xml(my_dictionary)
print(xml)
```

Comment: [Please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) reading the documentation first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following assigns an xml string to your variable xml.

```py
xml = dict2xml(my_dictionary)
```

You can do the string to a file by doing the following:

```py
from dict2xml import dict2xml
    
xml = dict2xml(my_dictionary)
with open("my_data.xml", 'w') as f:
    f.write(xml)
```

This will write your xml data to the file my_data.xml

Comment: thanks, but I got this error: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u06cc' in position

Comment: can you share how you have defined your dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a XML String and then write file-

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

xml_str = parseString(xml).toprettyxml()

save_path_file = "myfile.xml"  
with open(save_path_file, "w") as f:
    f.write(xml_str)
```

Comment: thanks but I got this error: junk after document element @Siddhant Sukhatankar